# Is there a way to find the number of points within a certain distance on one side of a border in ArcGIS?

Tags: mapping, arcgis, shapefile

I am working with about 3,000 GPS coordinates for schools in Rwanda and have mapped them to a district level shape-file. I am trying to figure out how many schools fall within 1km of each district border point for each district. I have converted the district borders to lines using the "Polygon to line" tool. And have used the Spacial Join feature to find the number of schools that fall within 1km of each line. But I want to know this within each polygon (within each district). So if border line 60 is the border that separates districts Rwamagana and Ngoma, I want to know how many schools fall within 1km of border 60 in Rwamagana and how many within 1km of border 60 in Ngoma.[Partial screenshot of Rwanda district map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc8SC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a buffer of 1km to your district polygons/polylines and use the spatial join afterwards, to determine how many schools fall within the study area.

If we take the border 60 in Rwamanagana for example, you would use the buffer-tool to add a buffer of 1km to that line, resulting in a polygon. This polygon can then be used in a spatial join to determine the number of schools inside of it.
See the [buffer-tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm) for more information.